# threads in OpenGL application

Tags: opengl

When running a simple  OpenGL application in windows there are two unknown threads .I want to know what is these threads in application ?are there any documentation about them? our application crash in one of this threads in first step i want to know what is these thread? .
[image]

and this is  dump of **nvoglv64**:
[image]

Comment: How do you feel about showing some code?

Comment: @filmor: Those are not threads created by the OP.

Comment: @datenwolf I'm aware of that, but he also wanted information on a crash happening. The assumption that the line resulting in the crash is in his code and not in the runtime is not far-fetched.

Comment: @filmor: Indeed. See my answer.

Comment: I have updated call stack .notice that nvoglc64.dll in call stack

Comment: after calling  **ChoosePixelFormat** these 2 thread run.

Comment: @jalalsadeghi: Well yes, it's very likely that NVidia's OpenGL implementation will start threads for internal use for housekeeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those threads are not something specific to OpenGL; OpenGL doesn't know anything about threads, because technically it's just a piece of text, namely the specification.

However in your case it's very likely that those threads are created by the OpenGL *implementation* (aka your graphics driver). As you can see those threads seem to be tasked with copying some data. Which suggest they crash, because you either give OpenGL

- some invalid pointer
- or invalid metrics for the pointer (size of the buffer, stride, etc.)
- or you're deallocating / freeing memory in a different thread while OpenGL still access it from the OpenGL context thread.

In either case it's not the threads fault that the program crashes, but *your* lack of either supplying OpenGL with valid data, or to properly lock/synchronize with OpenGL so that you don't invalidate the buffers in mid-operation.

#### Update

And this crash happening with Application Verifier suggests, that something about Application Verifier messes up memory used some way by OpenGL. This is very likely a bug in Application Verifier, but I think the best course of action would be to inform NVidia of the problem, so that they can address the problem with a workaround in their drivers.

Comment: when i run our application it crash at this stack. but when run a simple opengl Application with  **Application verifier** (Application Verifier is a runtime verification tool for unmanaged code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx) it crash at the same stack outside main thread.

Comment: it seems these threads are related to **Windows Extensions to OpenGL** (crating context,..)

Comment: @jalalsadeghi: It's fruitless to speculate what those threads do, because they are of no concern for you. Yes, they are created by the driver (nvogl64v.dll is the OpenGL implementation part of the NVidia drivers), but only NVidia knows what those threads do exactly. It's completely up to NVidia how they implement their OpenGL drivers. Now if OpenGL applications crash when run under Application Verifier this is either a bug of the OpenGL driver (report this to NVidia then) or Application Verifier (report this to Microsoft then).

Comment: @jalalsadeghi: Frankly I'd report this to NVidia, so that they can implement a workaround in their drivers. Wouldn't be the first time they address such a kind of bug that way, and definitely not the last.

Comment: I  think it is more a driver bug.because  it randomly occurs within our  application(Mediacal application with Volume rendering) about 2 or 3 hours one time.but  application verifier help to create it  earlier with event with a simple opengl application.